# How to set up Nimble server without really using WMSpanel?

Tags: video, streaming, panel, nimble

This has been asked before, and the accepted answer was to use WMSpanel which clearly did not answer the question of how to use it WITHOUT the panel.

Comment: https://wmspanel.com/nimble/install

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much to tell you about the rules.conf file as it is not properly documented, only that if you make a change you must ensure to tell Nimble to reload it's configuration after each file modification. Otherwise your config will be overwritten next time you open the panel.

To reload configuration from rules.conf use the aPI `/manage/reload_config[?drm=true]` as defined here https://softvelum.com/nimble/api/#toggler=16

Answer (score -1):

You can set it up via WMSPanel and remove server from the panel.

Check [this page](https://wmspanel.com/nimble/configure) regarding rules.conf . Once you change it, you can re-start Nimble or use [this API call](https://wmspanel.com/nimble/api#toggler=16) to re-load config.

Anyway you might consider using WMSPanel for more convenient handling of streaming scenario.